# Kentico Poll - How to get the number of voters for multiple choice question

Tags: kentico

I have a poll in Kentico with multiple choices. What Kentico reports is the number of votes but not the number of voters. Is there a way to get the number of voters (or the number of form submission each Question received).

Answer (score 0):

If you're using an EMS license, you can track activities that way.  Other than that, I don't believe there is a way to track how many times an individual person has submitted the poll.